# my android application doesn't appear on my phone when I installed it

Tags: android

I've developed my first Android application and I have published it on Google play, but when I try to install it, it installs but doesn’t appear on the phone.

Here is the **manifestAndroid.xml** , I believe that my configuration is the reason why.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="testconverteo.ismail.converteo"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.1b" >

    <uses-permission  android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET"  />
    <uses-permission  android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"  />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <!-- Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement-->


    <application
        android:name="Myapp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<!-- The BROWSABLE category is required in order for the intent filter to be accessible from a web browser -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.appconverteo.com/application” -->
                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="www.appconverteo.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/application" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginDisplayActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login_display" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

What should I do to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to separate the `.MainActivity` intent filter into two different intent filters.

one filter to appear on the launcher and a separate filter to be browsable.

```
         <!-- this makes it available to the launcher -->
         <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

         <!-- this makes it openable with browser -->
         <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.appconverteo.com/application” -->
                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="www.appconverteo.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/application" />
            </intent-filter>
```

ps.: you should test **BEFORE** pushing to Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

You should have 2 intent filters inside your manifest, one for each intent type you want to receive.

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="www.appconverteo.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/application" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

From android docs:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

> When you want to handle multiple kinds of intents, but only in
>   specific combinations of action, data, and category type, then you
>   need to create multiple intent filters.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my solution was to remove another intent filter I assigned to another activity I tested before. Maybe this helps someone.